# Audio not working

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le ch 2 48000 Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 341,33 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "VT1708S Digital"
        alsa.id = "VT1708S Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI SB"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI SB at 0xfe8f4000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "4383"
        device.product.name = "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (M4A785TD Motherboard)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Audio interno Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0
```

This is the configuration I have on my Mint Linux 20.1.  Audio does not work.  I installed Mint 17.3 with the same configuration and it does work there.

Comment: First step to debug this is to simplify: Take Pulseaudio out of the picture (e.g. via systemd/pasuspend/...), find a WAV file, and use `aplay -D ...` to play it directly via ALSA. If that does not work, the problem is in the audio drivers, so start reading `dmesg` (and if you have a working system to compare with, that makes it easier). If it does work, the problem is with your Pulseaudio configuration somehow, so start comparing `/etc/pulse`.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not very experienced, I need someone to give me directions on how to do it step by step